# Open source license to prevent publishing Android application with modified name or package

Tags: licensing

I've written an Android application and I want to publish it as a FOSS application, however, I want to restrict others from publishing it in Android markets (e.g. Play Store) with only changing the name or the package.
Which open source license should I use to achieve this requirement?

Comment: FYI, that restriction would automatically make your program "non-free" software (so not quite "FOSS"), as well as "non-open source" if you go by the OSI's definition, but wanting the software to be free/open except on one platform is still an interesting question so +1.

Comment: did you check prior questions here before asking? eg, [How can I compare and contrast open source licenses?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/120308/31260) and [Is there a chart for helping me decide between open-source licenses?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/105344/31260)